# Not receiving push notification after new installation

Tags: android, parsing, parse-platform, push

I'm using parse.com for receiving push notifications. It works fine until I install application again (through eclipse). Then I don't receive any notifications.

I need to uninstall application and remove a row from Installation table (parse.com) and install application, then I can receive push notifications again.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission
    android:name="com.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Application

```
Parse.initialize(this, "111", "222");
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
```

MainActivity

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

---

What I have to do if I want to receive push notify even I install new application version (from eclipse)

Comment: there is no problem in your code wait for some time notification come after some time

Comment: I haven't received any notifications since 3 days. If I uninstall app and install again I receive notifies. It was tested on 4 devices with different android version.

Comment: ckeck gcm id registered on parse.com are not

Comment: parse.com doesn't require gcm id. There is no field to type this id.

Comment: i m asking when u run install app gcm id registered on parse.com server check this

Comment: r u able to tell me where can I find this? How check this what you are saying?

Comment: here is some parse.com login id and password there  u create app for puch notification check on parse.com site see how many gcm id has been registered